# What is the difference in these two Python statements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, swig

I'm delving inside the code for [WiringPi-Python](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi2-Python) for Python and I found several blocks like this:

```
def wiringPiSetup():
  return _wiringpi2.wiringPiSetup()
wiringPiSetup = _wiringpi2.wiringPiSetup
```

This is a bit puzzling for me because I think that this:

```
def wiringPiSetup():
  return _wiringpi2.wiringPiSetup()
```

would yield exactly the same result as this:

```
wiringPiSetup = _wiringpi2.wiringPiSetup
```

I know that the first is declaring a new function, and the second is a reference to the original function, but in the tests I've made I find they are totally equivalent. Look here:

```
>>> def a():
...     return 4
... 
>>> def a1():
...     return a()
... 
>>> a2 = a
>>> 
>>> a1()
4
>>> a2()
4
```

So, why does WiringPi-Python put both when any of them will suffice?

**BTW:**

- I'm using Python 2.7.3
- This is the file where I saw that: [here](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi2-Python/blob/master/wiringpi2.py)

Comment: Eh? Good question, I have *no idea* why they'd do that.

Comment: Try removing one of the options. Does it break anything?

Comment: The first thing I notice is "This file is automatically generated by [swig](http://www.swig.org/)", which may explain the seemingly pointless statement. I have never used SWIG and have no idea why it would generate code like that, though.

Comment: what happens if, for some reason later on, someone does something like this: `_wiringpi2.wiringPiSetup = newfunc`? if you call the function version of `wiringPiSetup`, you'll probably get a different result.

Comment: @acushner Remember in Python assignment is just changing the names of things mostly. Your first example would rename `_wiringpi2.wiringPiSetup` to `newfunc` and do whatever `newfunc` does. If you still had a name referring to the original definition of `wiringPiSetup`, it would exhibit the original behavior.

Comment: yeah, that's what i was trying to convey. that if you wrapped the access to `_wiringpi2.wiringPiSetup` in a function call, you would get the most recently assigned behavior, whereas if you you used the direct assignment from when the file was imported, it might be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is generated by [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). The function definitions are indeed 'dead code', in that you can remove the function definition altogether and just leave the assignment in place.

Because the code is autogenerated, the code is somewhat inefficient. The [SWIG function that generates this code](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/fb96ff9613215782e65ff8500354b518e9d5cf06/Source/Modules/python.cxx#L2026-L2047), states:

```cpp
if (Getattr(n, "feature:python:callback") || !have_addtofunc(n)) {
  /* If there is no addtofunc directive then just assign from the extension module (for speed up) */
  Printv(f_dest, name, " = ", module, ".", name, "\n", NIL);
}
```

so the second assignment is there to just replace the generated Python function to speed up usage.

If the function has additional Python code to add when generating (`have_addtofunc()` is true when there is a docstring, a prepend or an append value) then the replacement line isn't generated.

Presumably the original function is left in place so that auto-completion tools can make use of the function signature.

Comment: 3 seconds difference on answering this question.

Comment: Nice research, both of you!

Comment: Thanks, it seems this is correct. I wonder anyway if that is the only reason to let that dead code in there.

Comment: @DWilches: it looks as if the [change was deliberate](https://github.com/swig/swig/commit/3d8ddfc442f1f73bc2c567aaa972680d14fea0df); it used to just not generate the function. That's a SVN commit converted to Git, so the original branch and commits for that branch are not (easily) retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

This file was generated by [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). From reading [SWIG Python generator soure code](http://sourceforge.net/p/swig/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Source/Modules/python.cxx#l1765) (`emitFunctionShadowHelper`) it seems the code generator creates a wrapper function if the wrapped function has some docstring, but then if the function does not has any docstring then the code generator issues a simple assign statement. It seems like an "`else`" clause might be added to the that function.